# How to write custom object to file in Android

Tags: android, file, object, serializable, objectoutputstream

```
private Map<String, List<DrawPath>> savedPath= new LinkedHashMap<String, List<DrawPath>>();
```

I want to write this "savedPath" to file, but throw a IOException:

```
public static class DrawPath implements Serializable{
        /**
         * 
         */
        public static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        public Path path;
                public Paint paint;
      }

 ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(sdFile));

out.writeObject(savedPath); // throws IOExcption
```

It works successfully if changed to `Map<String, String>`, is it relevant with my custom DrawPath class? How can I write this object to file success? Thanks

Comment: Please post your Logcat's error logs along with your question.

Comment: It catched by try {
     out.writeObject(savedPath);
    } catch (IOException e) {    

     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
    }

Comment: Umm, there is a logcat tab near the console tab. Your caught errors are printed over there when the app crashes. Please find all the error codes and strings in your logcat at the time of app crash and paste it with your question.

Comment: Do you know should I save Paint? Or how Serializable other object except DrawPath class?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all the objects you write to a file are Serializable, saving Paint maight be the problem

Comment: How should I save Paint? Or how Serializable other object except DrawPath class? Thanks very much!